# How to cross-check a value of a Gravity Forms email input field with current user email address in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I use Gravity Forms. I need to check if the given value in an `email` `input` field matches the current user's email address. For that, I am using the following code but the problem is when the field has CSS `visibility` property set to `hidden` the code doesn't validate the field. It let the user change the `default` value(current user email address) to a non-existing email address and submit the form. Apart from that, the code and the form are working properly.

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation_13_24', 'check_current_email', 10, 4 );
function check_current_email( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
    if ( $field->type === 'email' ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
  
        if ( empty( $value ) || ! email_exists( $value, $user->data->user_email, $user->ID ) ) {
            $result['is_valid'] = false;
            $result['message']  = 'Incorrect current user email. Please try again.';
        }
    }
  
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Visibility alone should not affect whether a form field submits a value or not.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the reply. Is the code correct? I see no error in my code. :(
By the way, the code works when I use the `display` property.

Comment: How exactly are you applying `visibility`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue please follow the steps. It's simple.

We need to add a `CSS` class(e.g.: `hidden-email`) for the email field and add some custom `CSS` on the page where we want to display the form. In this case, the `CSS` code would be `.hidden-email {display: none !important;}`